# Value of an Enum

Tags: c#

I'm little bit confused: Is this really the only method to read a value from an Enum-Code?

```
(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnumCode.ToString())
```

Something such essential and no better way to get the value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know, what you mean by "Enum-Code", but why not just convert it to an int?

```
int value = (int)MyEnum.MyEnumCode;
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you can just cast to int directly:

```
(int)MyEnum.MyEnumCode
```

Elaborating a bit. Internally an enum is actually an int. Therefore the cast is free. But it also means that you can easily have values in your enum that doesn't exist. E.g.

```
MyEnum val = (MyEnum)-123544;
```

Is perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 2):

What is it you want to achieve? Do you want the integer value associated with an enum? You can just cast the enum to int...

```
(int)MyEnum.MyEnumCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int x = MyEnumCode as int;
string y = MyEnumCode.ToString();
int z = (int)MyEnumCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
(int)MyEnumCode?
```

The underlying type for enum is int by default, so you can simply cast it.